# how to fix rigging problem, weight paint cannot fix

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, rigify

Here is a screenshot of my object, you can see the deformation. How to fix this problem.
I've tried every way but it still doesn't seem right. 
Please help me fix this, and tell me why this problem happened?

[image: with subtract in weight paint]
[image]

Comment: putting "please help me" in front of every sentence in not necessary to get an answer.

Comment: really, why u doing this... i need help love

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you're asking. From what I can tell, you need better weight painting. It also looks like you're bending bones in unnatural ways.